# VBA how to incorporate progress bar userform code to do loop

Tags: vba, progress

Need help to add the code correctly for userform progress bar.

```
For Each cel In rList
    Set fnd = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Database").Columns("A:A").Find(What:=cel.Value, LookAt:=xlWhole)
    If Not fnd Is Nothing Then
        fndFirst = fnd.Address
        Do
            fnd.Offset(0, 4).Value = cel.Offset(0, 4).Value
            fnd.Offset(0, 5).Value = cel.Offset(0, 5).Value
            fnd.Offset(0, 6).Value = cel.Offset(0, 6).Value
            fnd.Offset(0, 7).Value = cel.Offset(0, 7).Value
            fnd.Offset(0, 8).Value = cel.Offset(0, 8).Value
            fnd.Offset(0, 9).Value = cel.Offset(0, 9).Value
            fnd.Offset(0, 10).Value = cel.Offset(0, 10).Value

            Set fnd = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Database").Columns("A:A").FindNext(After:=fnd)
        Loop While fnd.Address <> fndFirst
    End If
Next
```

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: How is your userform progress bar updated? In general, you need to determine how many cells that are in your `rList` range, updating the progress bar each time you process a new cell. Insert your progress bar update line just below the `For Each cel In rList` line.

Comment: Hi PeterT thanks for the feedback, progress bar is updated til the last used row of A is processed.